# Is Update called based on screens refresh rate? MonoGame

Tags: monogame, frame-rate, vsync

My game is running 60fps (Because I'm using a 60hz monitor) but if I would use a 85hz monitor it would be running 85fps. My question is if update is called based on the screens refresh rate or if its limited to 60 calls per second

Comment: Some 60Hz monitors have an option in the settings to drop down to 30Hz. If you have that option, you could at least see if it actually drops downwards to 30fps.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea Shiro

Comment: Unfortunatly I just found out I can't do that with my monitor :|

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: It's not matter if you're using deltaTime based calculations.

Comment: it matters because if I do 60 * deltaTime on a 85hz monitor the result will be 0.7058823528 and that will look choppy right (if I don't use antialiasing and point filtering)

Comment: If you are moving objects by using `constant * deltaTime`, your movement will have the same speed for all frame rates

Comment: I know shiro.. but it will look choppy wright because I'm moving 0.7058823528 pixels every frame

Comment: But this has nothing with the question to do.. **Is Update called based on screens refresh rate?**

Comment: I know. It has to do with your previous comment. It definitely won't "be choppy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the fixed timestep in Monogame is 60 per seconds, regardless of the monitor refresh rate. The statement "it runs 85fps because my monitor refresh rate it 85hz" is false.

It just *tries* to give you 60 updates per second. It cannot *guarantee* it does, therefore using logic based on elapsed gametime is the best way to go.

If you want another timestep than 60, change the property `TargetElapsedTime` to the desired value. Again, this is unrelated to the refresh rate of your monitor since you can set the value yourself.

Read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/25/understanding-gametime.aspx for more information on how it is implemented in XNA (Monogame is based on this).